# How do I handle null/empty string/whitespace string in data-driven unit tests in Visual Studio, using CSV?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I want to do some data-driven testing in Visual Studio 2013, with the built-in testing framework. SQL is giving me endless headaches, XML looks messy, so that leaves CSV or Excel files.

I have some data-driven tests working with CSVs, but when I pull data from my CSV using `TestContext.DataRow[n]`, it converts whitespace strings, empty strings, and the string literal "NULL" to `DBNull`.  Even if I quote whitespace in my CSV, it still reads as `DBNull`.

At first, I was using the string literals "NULL" and "EMPTY" in my CSVs and converting them to `null` and `String.Empty` in my tests.  However, I now want to do some testing with various combinations of whitespace strings, so creating keywords to replace is going to get a lot more tedious and probably error-prone.

Is this over-nullification the proper behavior?  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't exactly the answer I was expecting, but it has made all my test data typing/deserialization issues disappear:

Switch to NUnit and use its `TestCase` feature.

Now my test data is written in good ol' C# source code.  I can't believe MSTest doesn't have an option for this.